# How do I get the last item in a MongoDB collection?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm using MongoDB for sometime to perform all sort of fast inserts or having as a log, but I'm having some trouble to get a **really simple query**

How, in Mongo, would I do to get a similiar to this T-SQL

```
SELECT TOP 1 [date] FROM [Collection] ORDER BY [date] desc
```

In other words, what is the last date in the collection.

I'm trying to use `FindOne` or any other that can return one document, but none accepts a `sortBy` property... how would I do this?

```
var query = Query.EQ("status", "pending");
var sortBy = SortBy.Descending("date");

return collectionLog.FindOneAs<BsonDocument>(query, sortBy);
```

The last line above would be perfect, but this method only accepts the `query` parameter.

Comment: my problem is the sorting, not how many will be returned

Comment: Yes you can't use findOne with sort (i think) so, use find with `limit` to do like a findOne sort

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no `.SetSortOrder()` method of `FindOneAs` in the C# driver.  This is because `FindOneAs` returns a document while `.SetSortOrder()` is a member of `MongoCursor`.

The equivalent query would be something similar to:

```
var query = Query.EQ("status", "pending");
var sortBy = SortBy.Descending("date");

return collectionLog.FindAs<BsonDocument>(query).SetSortOrder(sortby).SetLimit(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

As per version 1.4 the C# driver supports LINQ. I think something like this might help:

```
using MongoDB.Driver.Linq;

return collectionLog.AsQueryable().Where(l => l.status == "pending").AsQueryable().OrderByDescending(l => l.date);
```

Please note the first `AsQueryable()`, that is your neccessary start to LINQ into a Mongo collection.
The second `AsQueryable()` is neccessary because Where return IEnumerable, but `OrderByDescending()` takes IQueryable.

Comment: current version is 1.6.1 from [GitHub](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver)

Comment: I know the Linq part (hate it cause does not support `GroupBy`) but I'm always getting an Exception no matter what I do, I'm using MongoHQ as my mongoDB host.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it was usefull. gotta say though, the second AsQueryable() is not neccessary anymore since linq supports it.